# How to enable Robot framework fixing syntax error in the body response of API

Tags: robotframework

In my API test, I noticed that Robot Framework made some changes in the API response.

In fact, the actual result of my API post request is a JSON missing the “}”, but when I run this post request with robotframework I receive the JSON correct with the “}” at the end. So here, Robot Framework didn’t send me the response as it is sent from the server. It’s like that there is an option in robotframework that fix the syntax error automatically.
So how can I deactivate this option? because with this condition I can’t test correctly my API and detect if there is a bug or no?

I am using the RequestsLibrary library in mu test.

I am expecting to receive the response as it is sent from the server